# How to avoid ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES on AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

It's been a while since I have tried working with JavaScript, so please bear with me. I am working on an application that offers reports on student data. The backend is PHP.

The database that we use for these reports has to be refreshed from time to time from a central warehouse. The refresh happens at the discretion of the end user and is not automated for various reasons not worth going into here.

The refresh takes at least 10 minutes. So it would be painful for the browser to sit there loading for that amount of time with no feedback going to the user. I figured the best way to offer feedback to the user would be through a simple JQuery script that keeps the user up-to-date on the progress of the update.

**Here is the script:**

```js
    var n = 0;
    function increment() {
        n++;
        return n;
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#popme").click(function(event) {
            n = 0;
            $.getJSON('/path/to/json_pids', function(data) {
                var numRecords = data.length;
                $("#pop-result").html('<p>' + numRecords + ' records</p>');
                $.each(data, function(row) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/path/to/json_student_info/' + this,
                        success: function() {
                            increment();
                            $("#pop-result").html('<p>' + n + ' / ' + numRecords + ' records</p>');
                        }
                    });

                });
            });
        });
    });
```

**What's happening in this script:**

There's a `div` with the `pop-result` ID that gets updated. The `/path/to/json_pids` returns a JSON array of the matching student IDs.

From there, the script loops through each record and calls `/path/to/json_student_info/{student_id}`, but does not require anything in return. This second URL calls a script on the backend that creates/updates that student's record in the reporting database.

On success, the script is supposed to increment the number displayed in `pop-result` so that the user can see the progress toward completion of the script.

**The result and my question**

The result is a bit of a mess. The JS Console is showing a whole long line of `ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES` errors. The script never makes it all the way through all the records. It might reach ~4,000 out of ~11,000 records and just die from there.

I have a feeling I'm making a rookie mistake here. I've been looking for similar scenarios over the past couple of days but haven't found anything that helps. The best idea I can find is to break the data into chunks, but I still receive the same error and behavior. Is there an alternative/better way to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish, or a way to make this script less intensive on the browser?

Comment: you're sending 11k ajax requests as fast as the browser will allow to the server. that's quite a bit of processing. Maybe *throttle* it back a bit.

Comment: Sounds like you're inadvertingly causing a [DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) style drag on your server which is not surprising if you take into account that the async nature of the `$.ajax` call will allow the browser to launch a large amount of requests in a super short time period. I'm thinking that you're consuming all available resources, filling the request pool or app pool, and then dying. You could try launching each subsequent request after the first in the success callback of the previous `$.ajax` call.

Comment: I agree. I thought about trying some type of method to slow down the requests to the server. I realize turning off `async` is deprecated in JQuery and would defeat the purpose anyway. Another method, using a library called [Frame](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js) doesn't look like a good solution either, as it appears to no longer be maintained.

Comment: @Joeventures I've added an answer below that makes use of callbacks in a recursive nature to throttle the number of requests sent. In essence, it acts like `async: true` would but in a non-locking asynchronous state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure the following code still be optimized but here is a throttled approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Declare variable to hold data...
    var results = [],
        length = 0;

    $("#popme").click(function(event) {

        // Get Data
        $.getJSON('/path/to/json_pids', function(data) {

            // Store returned results in value accessible by all functions
            results = data;
            length = results.length;

            $("#pop-result").html('<p>' + length + ' records</p>');

            processItem();
        });
    });

    function processItem() {
        // Check length, if 0 quit loop...
        if(results.length) {
            // Make a call always referencing results[0] since we're shfiting the array results...
            $.ajax({
                url: '/path/to/json_student_info/' + results[0],
                success: function() {
                    $("#pop-result").html('<p>' + ((length - results.length) + 1) + ' / ' + length + ' records</p>');
                    // Remove the first item to prepare for next iteration...
                    results.shift();
                    // Yay! for recursive functions...
                    processItem();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This should in theory, recursively call your service with the next item after the previous item has finished processing. In other words, it will make the operations seem synchronous as only one at a time will be processed, but it's using callbacks as oppose the the `async` flag as you mentioned above that that flag is deprecated.

Comment: It's running right now and looks like it's working like a charm. This is a great solution. I really like this approach. Apparently the browser and server both like it, too. Many thanks!

Comment: @War10ck thanks for the nice solution. I got a really heavy load to process with this approach the resource utilization is well managed.

Comment: Well here I am in 2020, while this approach works for me, if I have 5000 ajax requests and each of them on an average takes, half a second, my entire process is taking over half an hour :-(

 is there a way, we could fire 100 or 50 batches of requests at a time?

Comment: i also got the same error.
i am uploading the file with javascript to AzureBlob I am uploading around 5000 files in one click. 
its also shows me the same error in the middle of the upload. i did nothing. chrome itself.  restarted the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

i so requested 5800 ajax at once and i have this Error

#### How I Fix it :

i set delay after 10 times of ajax and progress bar loading for user

**You Can Change Times**

Link 1: [(stackoverflow.com) Delay With Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350746/using-settimeout-with-ajax-calls)

Link 2: [(stackoverflow.com) Use SetTimeout in For loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values)

here is code:

```
// Define this Function as Global | Link 1
var myAjaxConnection = function (param = null) {
        $.ajax({ /* Your Config */});
    }
// Define this Function as Global too | Link 2
function runTheTimeout(time, param = null){
    setTimeout(function(){myAjaxConnection(param)}, time);
}
// My Code 
arr = [1..5800]; // IMPORTANT: Your data
var timesLimit = 10;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var time = ((i % timesLimit ) == 0) ? 15000 : ((i % timesLimit ) * 300);
    runTheTimeout(time); // You Can Send Param Too :] 
}
```