# Query execution after a few seconds

Tags: php

I have a script that records all page views on my site that I've uploaded, and it's working fine. But now there are some problems with GOOGLE visitation, and there is "a lot", more "much" visitation of the Google Robots and it is not legal to have a WebSite visitation base.

There was a need for only the function setCounterVisitor(); to be executed after 15 seconds, because my script would be required on another page. It is important that to function to come it is on the same page and not on visitor.php.

```
<?php 
require_once 'app/visitor.php'; 
setCounterVisitor();
?>
```

You can run setCounterVisitor(); after 15 seconds on the loaded page?

Comment: So wait 15 seconds on page load to run `setCounterVisitor();`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350746/using-settimeout-with-ajax-calls
 - use that way

Comment: call ajax after 5 to 10 second after page load

Comment: I do not know how to call setcountervisitor (); through ajax. Given that the examples are for submission of forms, which is not my case. I could not do that.

Comment: @hungrykoalahum how to make friend

Comment: Can use JS timeout function https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: @ChickenFeet How will it work with the setcountervisitor (); is in visitor.php PHP
My script is based on this:
https://kodekuliahan.blogspot.com.br/2018/01/cara-membuat-visitor-counter-dengan-php.html

Comment: Use an Ajax call as someone previously mentioned. Ajax call after 15 seconds are up.